# Upgrading Old PHP & MySQL - Red Hat

Tags: php, mysql, redhat

Ok, I've got a an old box running Red Hat and MySQL 3.23.49 and PH 4.1.2 and I just want to upgrade them enough to run Wordpress 3 on that server without messing up a site I have using that PHP and MySQL setup. I'm not against being completely up to date, just don't want to break what I've got.

Looks like I just need: PHP 4.3 & MySQL 4.1.2 to make this happen. Do I need to worry about the compatibility and if not, is there an RPM file or something that I can use to do this through the webmin or command line? and am I likely to have no compatibility problems?

or should i just setup a second instal of apache/mysql/php on that box in another directory?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're more then likely to have compatibility issues because a lot has been deprecated. I would suggest doing a full update to the latest versions and just fixing a few codes.

That's my suggestion but whatever makes you happy.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I'm not against being completely up to date, just don't want to break what I've got.

Unfortunately, if you're running out of date versions of PHP, especially if very out of date, then what you have is already broken, albeit in a less obvious way. Much better to have a few hours of suffering now, making sure everything is up to date, than later when someone turns your server into their own personal porn link farm.

Best way to proceed is to set up a dev environment, where you can run a copy of the code without worrying about user-facing problems and get the code up to date before updating your main server.